# Overriding window.location on Webbrowser Control

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control, iwebbrowser2

This might seem a weird question, but is there a way to override the window.location without making the browser control navigate to it? The problem I am having is that i am injecting html code in the control, and the window.location is about:blank - causing errors on some javascript code. Trying to make them think they are in a URL other than about:blank

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

I've had success with **Object.defineProperty()** when `document.documentMode >= 9` (IE9+).

To get the WebBrowser control in IE9+ mode, I first load the following URL:

```
about:<!doctype html><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

This gives a mostly empty document in the latest document mode.

Then to redefine `window.location`, I execute some script via eval() or document.write():

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {value: {href: 'fubar'}});
```

The complete sequence is like this:

- Load the control.
- Wait for `WebBrowser.ReadyState == 4` or the `DocumentComplete` event.
- Call `document.open()` (important).
- Eval or write the script redefining *location*.
- Write the HTML content.
- Call `document.close()` (ensures onload gets called).

Note: I use the ActiveX [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040) control, and not the .NET component which is a wrapper around that control. It will probably work the same in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 drafts include [`window.history.pushState`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-history-pushstate)+[`window.onpopstate`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#handler-window-onpopstate), but this is not supported by Trident (MSHTML), and doesn't allow for navigating across domains, nevermind URL schemes.

Some JavaScript implementations also support user-defined getters and setters, so you could maybe do `window.__defineGetter__('location', function() { return fakeLocation })`, but yet again I believe that won't work with IE's control.

Echoing the commenters: what are you doing?

Comment: A little hard to explain on a public forum, but hacking the control pretty much to display certain code i want to display and monitor. the problem is they have JavaScript that checks on the window.location - which breaks. Of course the answer could be dont inject in the browser, navigate to a URL - but i was trying to avoid that.

Comment: Won't work. `Unhandled Error: __defineGetter__: invalid modification of non-configurable property`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to replace the `window.location` property. `window.location` is a non-configurable property, which means that it cannot be modified.

The only messy workaround that I can use is to do a find and replace (replace the `window.location` line with an empty string or something) on the script text before executing it.